# Position "fixed" se move quando descer a página no celular

Tags: css, posicionamento

Crie um `div` com `position:fixed;top:0`.
No computar fica normal, e não se move independente se desço ou subo a tela, mas no celular quando desço a tela ele sai, mas se subo novamente ele aprece fixo no topo de novo.
Alguém sabe como resolver isso? abaixo como esta o div:

```
<div class="menu">
  MENU
</div>

.menu{
 position:fixed;
 z-index:9;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Vc tem certeza que está position:fixed? Ou está position:stciky? Vc usa algum jQuery ou JS nesse menu para mudar o tamanho ou algo do tipo quando rola a tela?

Comment: Mas não é o fixed que desce quando se rola a página? acho que o que você queria era o absolute.

Comment: descobri o problema. Tinha uma textarea que a largura passava da tela, aí só arrumei a largura dele e voltou ao normal